# How to make a dynamic framework(Swift) based on two static libraries using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I want to make a dynamic framework that incorporates two 3-rd party frameworks with static libraries and later add it as a pod to my project.
Here are their podspec files

- [IndoorsSDK-iOS.podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/3/a/0/IndoorsSDK-iOS/4.4.0/IndoorsSDK-iOS.podspec.json) (By the way, this one lacks modulemap in .framework file)
- [IndoorAtlas.podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/3/d/IndoorAtlas/2.4.1/IndoorAtlas.podspec.json)

I tried to add them as `s.dependency` in my podspec file but got following error
`Pods error - target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries`

Tried to include them as `s.vendored_frameworks` but got following https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6409 and can't make workaround with the given solution.

Could you help with the direction how I can deal with it and later I'll
post some test project to look at the issue closer. Now I simply have so many different test projects that don't work that I don't even know what to post to Github to show.

In most of my attempts I ended up not being able to use Import IndoorsSDK/IndoorAtlas in my framework swift files because **"No such module"** error.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution. So, in case someone run into similar issue, I post it here.

My **`podspec`** file except other lines contains following

```
#// one library added as dependency, another as vendored_frameworks
#// because it lacks modulemap, so it was added manually to IndooRS framework
spec.dependency 'IndoorAtlas'
spec.vendored_frameworks = 'SKNavigation/Frameworks/IndoorsSDK.framework'

#// following lines fix linking issues so our pod would see dependency modules
spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) $(SRCROOT)/**',
    'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -undefined dynamic_lookup'
  }
```

And **`modulemap`**, that was added to the Framework that lacked it

```
module IndoorsSDK [system] {
    header "Headers/IndoorsSDK.h"
    header "Headers/Indoors.h"
    export *
    link framework "CoreMotion"
    link framework "CoreBluetooth"
    link "c++"
}
```

The latest point, **`podfile`** should contain following to hide transitive dependencies error.

```
pre_install do |installer|
    def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
end
```

And that's probably all.